# bulkactions with dropdown list yii booster

Tags: yii

Is there a way to have a dropdown option rather than a link or button or... buttongroup as the buttonType?

```
$this->widget ( 'bootstrap.widgets.TbExtendedGridView', array (
        'id'=>'grid',
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'bulkActions' => array(
            'actionButtons' => array(
            array(
                'buttonType' => 'select',//?
                'type' => 'primary',
                'size' => 'small',
                'label' => 'Batch',
                    'url' => array('batchUpdate'),
                    'id' => 'child_id',
                    'click' => ''
                )
        ),....
```

Comment: Have a look at: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/106/using-cbuttoncolumn-to-customize-buttons-in-cgridview/